# Difficulty switching company

Tags: india

I am a Data scientist working in an Oil and Gas company in India for the last one year. Despite of my designation as a "Data Scientist", I was hardly provided with projects in which there has been any requirement of data analysis or machine learning model development. My work mainly deals with developing Python applications which use OpenCV and TesseractOCR and developing UI using Tkinter and packaging them as exe using pytesseract.

I feel that this work is not Data Science, and so am actively applying for Data Science roles involving SQL, Excel and Python to perform data analysis which would aid in making business decisions. I get through the resume qualification, coding rounds, business case studies, etc. but am unable to crack a single interview. I have given multiple interviews but have been rejected on the ground that the kind of work that I am doing at my current role does not fit with their role.

I am really finding it difficult to switch to another company and work as a real Data Scientist. I am skilled in data analysis as is evident in my cracking the coding and business case study rounds. What do I do? Please help!

Comment: I believe they have no issues with my background and so I am qualifying the resume shortlisting round (which includes the cover letter). The issue is that the kind of work I do at my current company does not match their expectations.

Comment: Which they understand in depth during the interview round, and so I am receiving rejects and being told that I am unfit for the role.

Comment: Uhhh don’t do what Rob suggested.  Wow.

Answer (score 5):

Brush it off and just keep applying, you're still new in your career relatively speaking.

There is nothing you can do about your current job, so don't let it detract from your self-confidence. If you're getting to the final round you're doing better than many others.

Emphasize that your skillset and interests are in data science which is why you're applying for their job, and downplay anything irrelevant to that.

Answer (score 3):

1. Be aware you are really, *really*, lucky to be working in oil & gas in the region. I wish I was. **I urge you to aggressively and politely remind and ask your current boss that you need some Data Science tasks.** Do your current tasks with great enthusiasm but in each instance clearly (yet politely) state that you need Data Science tasks.
2. Regarding your couple of rejections, my company had 7 rejections last week. It's a non-issue, keep going.

Comment: I urged him for the same. But he said the tasks he is giving me are what constitute urgent priority. When I got a little angry despite of reminding him multiple times, he even said that the company is paying me to do the work he wants me to do and he does not care whether I am interested in doing the work or not.

Comment: @CommonMan well done.  In that case just wait for your "2" opportunity.  But do remember the fact that you already have experience in O&G is priceless.  Enjoy!!